# Which transducer models replacement in regex?

Tags: regular-expressions, pushdown-automata, transducers

I am looking for the right transducer which allows to translate a sequence of literals into a sequence of same literals (or a subset of them) in arbitrary order. 
For example: ABC => CAB, which, with simple production rules:
A->a, B->b, C->c, results into output: *cab*.

I am not sure if the pushdown automata is enough to resolve such problem.

Note: My question corresponds to understand which automaton model lies under the implementation of the widely used regex replacement strategy in common libraries such as: back reference in java([link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#grouping-and-back-reference)) or replacement part in sed of bash  ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)).